# Wildfly Logging Profile Setting ( logger.debug("test") )

Tags: java, logging, wildfly, jboss-logging, jboss-cli

I would like to create a profile for my application's logs

I need to use `logger.debug()` but if I put down in the `standalone.xml` file DEBUG I get too many lines

from `<level name="INFO"/>` to `<level name="DEBUG"/>`

```
.....................
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
......................
```

I can create a profile that enables only debug logging of my application?

I created my profile and add in my MANIFEST.MF but it does not work

```
<logging-profiles>
   <logging-profile name="accounts-app-profile">
       <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
           <level name="DEBUG"/>
           <formatter>
              <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
       </console-handler>
       <file-handler name="ejb-trace-file">
           <level name="DEBUG"/>
           <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="ejb-trace.log"/>
       </file-handler>
       <logger category="com.company.accounts.ejbs">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="ejb-trace-file"/>
            </handlers>
       </logger>
       <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
           <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
       </formatter>
</logging-profile>
```

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Logging-Profile: accounts-app-profile
```

Call the Logger

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.company.accounts.ejbs");

logger.debug("debug");
logger.info("info");
```

the file `ejb-trace.log` creates but does not write inside

Comment: What type of deployment is this?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins war file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A logging profile should not be required for what you're attempting to do. Assuming the category `com.company.accounts.ejbs`and assuming you want messages from your application to be logged into their own file the following CLI commands will

```
/subsystem=logging/file-handler=ejb-trace-file:add(level=DEBUG, file={relative-to=jboss.server.log.dir, path=ejb-trace.log}, autoflush=true)
/subsystem=logging/logger=com.company.accounts.ejbs:add(level=DEBUG, handlers=[ejb-trace-file], use-parent-handlers=false)
```

If you also want the messages logged to the console handler or the server.log you can remove the `use-parent-handlers=false` attribute or set it to `true`.

Comment: I solved changing in handler console DEBUG instead of INFO<console-handler name="CONSOLE"><level name="DEBUG"/></console-handler>

Answer (score 1):

This may be old post, since I came across this post to solve my issue which is described above, someone in future can also read this. For this reason I wanted to share my answer here.

In my case I have followed this post https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.2/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/example_logging_profile_configuration and couple of other and created `<logging-profile>` in `standalone.xml` file in `wildFly server` and created `MANIFEST.MF` file manually in `\src\main\resources\META_INF` folder, then the log file got created but the log content is not writing inside of that.

The reason is my application is using maven for build config and creating manifest file.

If the application is using `maven` for build configurations or `maven` plugin to create `manifest.mf` file then you have to add the below information in your application's `pom.xml` file.

- if the application is using `maven` for build configurations, then add below lines in `pom.xml` `<build> <plugins>` tag

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

- if the application is using `maven` plugin to create `manifest.mf` file then add below lines in `pom.xml` `<manifestEntries>` i.e. in

```
<build> 
   <plugins> 
     <plugin> 
       <archive> 
        <manifestEntries> 
          <Logging-Profile>myAppLogProfile</Logging-Profile> 
        </manifestEntries>
```

after adding this, if you do `mvn clean` and `mvn install` then the `Logging-Profile: myAppLogProfile` line will be added to your `MANIFEST.MF` file in war file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Logging-Profile: myAppLogProfile
```

after this when I redeploy it, the log file has log content in it.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the root-logger, but add a category that matches the package name you wish to debug

Comment: The error you made was to change the root-logger in the standalone xml. Change that back to INFO

Comment: For simplicity, I would just add your <logger category entries to the standalone xml too rather rush bothering trying to define a logging profile

Comment: where do I have to add <logger-category> entries? you can give me an example. thank you

Comment: in <subsystem xmlns = "urn: jboss: domain: logging: 3.0">

Comment: Just above the <root-logger add <logger category="com.company"> <level name="DEBUG"/> </logger>

Comment: I added <logger category="com.company"> <level name="DEBUG"/> </logger> and declared final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("com.company"); 
but does not print DEBUG, only INFO

Comment: Where are you looking? console or server.log?

Comment: both of them, but do not print in files or on the console

Comment: yes, it works INFO, FATAL, WARN, ERROR but not DEBUG

Comment: Do you still have <level name="DEBUG"/> inside the CONSOLE declaration in standalone?

Comment: no, both above and below, <console-handler name="CONSOLE"<level name="INFO"/> and <root-logger><level name="INFO"/>.I also deleted the MANIFEST file and tried to run with standalone.sh --debug